# How do i code a scrolling window to stay at a certain link per page

Tags: html, css

On [this page](http://DinosauriaOnline.com), I want to get my scrolling dinosaur name window to specifically keep that dinosaurs name at the top so the person doesn't have to scroll all the way down to the next dinosaur.

I also want to know if there's an easier way to do this window.

My predicament is this....

I have over 30 dinosaurs on here. Each time I add a new one I have to update each and every one of the dinosaurs pages to add that one new dinosaur. Its not really time effective... Is there a better way without having to use frames?

My code is open so you can look at it and modify it at your leasure.

Thanks!
Vince

Comment: Do you use any back-end scripting, like PHP? This would be well-suited for a database of dinosaurs and a dynamically loaded list, so you could write it to put the dinosaur of the current page first.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I would suggest you go for server side code. Since you have 30 dinosaurs, it would be much easier to create and maintain a simple page using server side scripts such as **PHP** or **ASP.NET** to load the dinosaur from a database.

**What are server side scripts?** 
Server side scripts allow you to dynamically generate a page on the fly whenever the user requests a page. For example, take youtube's search page. Rather than generate a seperate page for every single possible search term, they simply have a base template there, and then they fetch the relevant results based on the search query. The same can be applied to your site. You can have **one** page for **all** the dinosaurs, and you would just load the appropriate dinosaur based on the url.

Once you do that, putting the current dinosaur at the top of the page would be a trivial task. Since it appears that you already have a fair amount of knowledge in HTML, it should be easy for you to pick up and use some PHP. [**Codecademy**](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php) has some excellent tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as Kevins answer but more specifically I'd like to recommend you look into a PHP MVC framework such as [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org), [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) or [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter).

You've done all the hard work manually building these pages, which is awfully time consuming.

Once you learn one of these frameworks and you'll rebuild this site in a day.

Answer (score 0):

If your links had `id` attributes on them you could scroll the list to a position by linking to `#whatever`. Here's a quick code example of a link.

```
<li id="camarasaurus"><a href="Camarasaurus.html#camarasaurus">Camarasaurus</a></li>
```

Here's a small example: http://jsbin.com/ExExEvAB/1/edit?html,css,output

As for making it easier to administrate, I'd look into PHP since it's widely available and there's tons of resources to learn from. When you're basically looking for is `<?php include "dinosaur-menu.html" ?>` since you're thinking in terms of frames. You can make it even easier but this alone should make it a ton easier to update.

I really started to enjoy [Mixture](http://mixture.io/) recently. It's great for prototyping and is, in my opinion, perfect for exactly what you're trying to do here.